# Zend Form Multiselect Question

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms

The following is a drop down menu I am trying to add to a Zend Form.  Currently the value of the form is 0 for Running and 1 for Triathlon.  Instead I want the values to be the same as the labels.  What am I doing wrong?  I checked Google but seems like I am doing it right. I have checked this against another one and they seem to be the same.

```
   $types = array('Running'=>'Running', 'Triathlon'=>'Triathlon');

    $type = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('type');
    $type->setLabel('Type')
          ->setRequired(true) 
          ->addFilter('StripTags') 
          ->addFilter('StringTrim') 
          ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $type->setMultiOptions($types);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was outside this code.  The form was the wrong one.